# Activar GPU al entrenar un modelo en Tensorflow Ubuntu

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

Mi duda es simple quiero poder activar el entrenamiento con GPU en linux Ubuntu para ir mas rapido la cosa es que ya instale cuda y seguí el tutorial del [sitio oficial](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements) y cuando intento entrenar un modelo me dice que lo esta haciendo con el cpu ademas de enviar 3 errores mas que no entiendo pero tienen que ver con el cpu, la salida es esta

```
frijol@frijolito:~/Cats$ python3 train.py 
2019-12-31 14:50:54.000267: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2019-12-31 14:50:54.254632: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2299965000 Hz
2019-12-31 14:50:54.255726: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x2c661b0 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-12-31 14:50:54.255784: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
```

ademas para verificar si la gpu esta disponible uso esta funcion: `print(tf.test.is_gpu_available())` pero me manda que no, osea False

la verdad no se que hacer asi que si alguien sabe como solucionarlo seria de mucha ayuda, use conda para instalar Tensorflow si es que sirve de algo

Comment: ¿Tu tarjeta de video soporta eso?

Comment: Si lo soporta, tengo gtx 1050

Comment: Prueba con esto: https://medium.com/@soumyadipmajumder/complete-guide-to-tensorflow-gpu-installation-on-windows-10-36e5858640e9

Comment: Mi sistema operativo es ubuntu, error mio me falto especificar eso, de todas formas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: en ese caso, mirad: https://gist.github.com/tonussi/2bf7bf60c8d7b7a2134a56677042d8f5

Comment: Es raro que siguiendo todos los pasos del sitio oficial, no te funcione. Yo probaría a desinstalar todos los drivers y paquetes de Nvidia y Tensorflow e instalaría Tensorflow-gpu de nuevo y los paquetes tal y como viene en la explicación